# Round pandas datetime index?

Tags: datetime, python-2.7, pandas, resampling

I am reading multiple spreadsheets of timeseries into a pandas dataFrame and concatenating them together with a common pandas datetime index. The datalogger that logged the timeseries is not 100% accurate which makes resampling very annoying because depending on if the time is slightly higher or lower than the interval being sampled it will create NaNs and starts to make my series look like a broken line. Here's my code

```
def loaddata(filepaths):
    t1 = time.clock()
    for i in range(len(filepaths)):
        xl = pd.ExcelFile(filepaths[i])
        df = xl.parse(xl.sheet_names[0], header=0, index_col=2, skiprows=[0,2,3,4], parse_dates=True)
        df = df.dropna(axis=1, how='all') 
        df = df.drop(['Decimal Year Day', 'Decimal Year Day.1', 'RECORD'], axis=1)

        if i == 0:
            dfs = df
        else:
            dfs = concat([dfs, df], axis=1)
    t2 = time.clock()
    print "Files loaded into dataframe in %s seconds" %(t2-t1)

files = ["London Lysimeters corrected 5min.xlsx", "London Water Balance 5min.xlsx"]
data = loaddata(files)
```

Here's an idea of the index:

> data.index
>
> class 'pandas.tseries.index.DatetimeIndex'>
>   [2012-08-27 12:05:00.000002, ..., 2013-07-12 15:10:00.000004]
>   Length: 91910, Freq: None, Timezone: None

What would be the fastest and most general to round the index to the nearest minute?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's a little trick. Datetimes are in nanoseconds (when viewed as `np.int64`).
So round to minutes in nanoseconds.

```
In [75]: index = pd.DatetimeIndex([ Timestamp('20120827 12:05:00.002'), Timestamp('20130101 12:05:01'), Timestamp('20130712 15:10:00'), Timestamp('20130712 15:10:00.000004') ])

In [79]: index.values
Out[79]: 
array(['2012-08-27T08:05:00.002000000-0400',
       '2013-01-01T07:05:01.000000000-0500',
       '2013-07-12T11:10:00.000000000-0400',
       '2013-07-12T11:10:00.000004000-0400'], dtype='datetime64[ns]')

In [78]: pd.DatetimeIndex(((index.asi8/(1e9*60)).round()*1e9*60).astype(np.int64)).values
Out[78]: 
array(['2012-08-27T08:05:00.000000000-0400',
       '2013-01-01T07:05:00.000000000-0500',
       '2013-07-12T11:10:00.000000000-0400',
       '2013-07-12T11:10:00.000000000-0400'], dtype='datetime64[ns]')
```

Comment: Works perfect and is very fast! I didn't know you could treat the datetimeindex this way

Comment: you actually *have* to handle them way under the hood (which the ``index`` hides for the most part)

Comment: this could also be a nice addition to the index code, you can follow this issue: https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/4314

Answer (score 4):

Issue [4314](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/4314) mentioned by Jeff is now closed and `round()` method was added for DatetimeIndex, Timestamp, TimedeltaIndex and Timedelta in pandas 0.18.0. Now we can do the following:

```
In[109]: index = pd.DatetimeIndex([pd.Timestamp('20120827 12:05:00.002'), pd.Timestamp('20130101 12:05:01'), pd.Timestamp('20130712 15:10:30'), pd.Timestamp('20130712 15:10:31')])

In[110]: index.values
Out[110]: 
array(['2012-08-27T12:05:00.002000000', '2013-01-01T12:05:01.000000000',
       '2013-07-12T15:10:30.000000000', '2013-07-12T15:10:31.000000000'], dtype='datetime64[ns]')

In[111]: index.round('min')
Out[111]: 
DatetimeIndex(['2012-08-27 12:05:00', '2013-01-01 12:05:00',
               '2013-07-12 15:10:00', '2013-07-12 15:11:00'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq=None)
```

`round()` accepts frequency parameter. String aliases for it are listed [here](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timeseries.html#offset-aliases).

Answer (score 0):

For data columns; 
Use: round_hour(df.Start_time)

```
def round_hour(x,tt=''):
    if tt=='M':
        return pd.to_datetime(((x.astype('i8')/(1e9*60)).round()*1e9*60).astype(np.int64))
    elif tt=='H':
        return pd.to_datetime(((x.astype('i8')/(1e9*60*60)).round()*1e9*60*60).astype(np.int64))
    else:   
        return pd.to_datetime(((x.astype('i8')/(1e9)).round()*1e9).astype(np.int64))
```