# Interpolating a large dataframe onto a sparse, irregular index

Tags: python, pandas, interpolation

I've got one dataframe containing several years of data sampled at 30 min intervals (7 parameters from a continuous water quality sensor), and I've got another dataframe containing data at a few hundred random points in time, with one minute precision.  I'd like to find the interpolated values of the 7 parameters at the few hundred random points in time.

So here's a few lines of what these dataframes look like:

```
print df1    
                    Temp  SpCond   Sal  DO_pct  DO_mgl  Depth   pH  Turb
2002-07-16 14:00:00  26.0   45.31  29.3    71.6     4.9   0.95  7.9    -5
2002-07-16 14:30:00  25.9   45.22  29.2    70.4     4.9   0.98  7.9    -6
2002-07-16 15:00:00  26.0   44.92  29.0    76.2     5.3   1.02  7.9    -6
2002-07-16 15:30:00  26.0   45.06  29.1    77.9     5.4   1.06  7.9    -5
2002-07-16 16:00:00  25.9   45.23  29.2    67.0     4.6   1.11  7.8    -6
2002-07-16 16:30:00  25.9   45.33  29.3    72.9     5.0   1.17  7.9    -6
2002-07-16 17:00:00  25.9   45.46  29.4    65.8     4.5   1.21  7.9    -6
2002-07-16 17:30:00  25.9   45.40  29.4    70.5     4.9   1.19  7.9    -6
2002-07-16 18:00:00  25.9   45.27  29.3    74.3     5.1   1.15  7.9    -6
2002-07-16 18:30:00  25.8   45.57  29.5    67.6     4.7   1.11  7.8    -6
...

print df2
                      PO4F   NH4F   NO2F   NO3F  NO23F  CHLA_N
DateTimeStamp                                                 
2002-07-16 14:01:00  0.053  0.073  0.005  0.021  0.026     8.6
2002-07-16 16:05:00  0.029  0.069  0.002  0.016  0.018     9.6
2002-07-16 18:09:00  0.023  0.073  0.000    NaN  0.014     5.8
...
```

I want to find the values of df1 at the index values of df2, but the only way I can figure out from reading the docs and other stackoverflow answers is by putting df1 on a one minute time base (which will generate a bunch of nans), then filling the nans using Series.interpolate, and then pulling out the one minute values at the discrete times of df2.   That seems incredibly wasteful.  There must be another way, right?

Comment: You wrote: "I want to find the values of df1 at the index values of df2".  Do you mean the closest value from df1, the next time index after df2 in df1, the time index before...?  In other words (from your example) should the first row of df2 match to 14:00 or 14:30?

Comment: I want to linearly interpolate the 30 minute data to the exact time values of the sparse data. I don't want the nearest values.  For example, I want the values of df1 at 16:05, interpolated from the values of df1 at 16:00 and 16:30.

Answer (score 1):

If you want interpolation, I think you're stuck with the method you describe, or something approximately as "wasteful." If you can setting for taking the most recent value or the next value, use `ffill` or `bfill` respectively.

```
In [34]: df1.reindex(df2.index, method='ffill')
Out[34]: 
                     Temp  SpCond   Sal  DO_pct  DO_mgl  Depth   pH  Turb
DateTimeStamp                                                            
2002-07-16 14:01:00  26.0   45.31  29.3    71.6     4.9   0.95  7.9    -5
2002-07-16 16:05:00  25.9   45.23  29.2    67.0     4.6   1.11  7.8    -6
2002-07-16 18:09:00  25.9   45.27  29.3    74.3     5.1   1.15  7.9    -6
```

Comment: A bit off topic, but is there any reason `interpolate()` doesn't offer any of the scipy functions for interpolation?  I could see something like `method='spline'` working to fill `NaNs` and for resampling.  I can start a github issue (and get around to implementing it someday) if anyone thinks it would be useful.

Comment: Definitely! I haven't wanted this for awhile but haven't spoken up about it yet.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a way to do what I think you want

Starting frame df1 and df2

```
In [100]: df1
Out[100]: 
                     Temp  SpCond   Sal  DO_pct  DO_mgl  Depth   pH  Turb
time                                                                     
2002-07-16 14:00:00  26.0   45.31  29.3    71.6     4.9   0.95  7.9    -5
2002-07-16 14:30:00  25.9   45.22  29.2    70.4     4.9   0.98  7.9    -6
2002-07-16 15:00:00  26.0   44.92  29.0    76.2     5.3   1.02  7.9    -6
2002-07-16 15:30:00  26.0   45.06  29.1    77.9     5.4   1.06  7.9    -5
2002-07-16 16:00:00  25.9   45.23  29.2    67.0     4.6   1.11  7.8    -6
2002-07-16 16:30:00  25.9   45.33  29.3    72.9     5.0   1.17  7.9    -6
2002-07-16 17:00:00  25.9   45.46  29.4    65.8     4.5   1.21  7.9    -6
2002-07-16 17:30:00  25.9   45.40  29.4    70.5     4.9   1.19  7.9    -6
2002-07-16 18:00:00  25.9   45.27  29.3    74.3     5.1   1.15  7.9    -6
2002-07-16 18:30:00  25.8   45.57  29.5    67.6     4.7   1.11  7.8    -6

In [101]: df2
Out[101]: 
                      P04F   NH4F   N02F   N03F  NO23F  CHLA_N
time                                                          
2002-07-16 14:01:00  0.053  0.073  0.005  0.021  0.026     8.6
2002-07-16 16:05:00  0.029  0.069  0.002  0.016  0.018     9.6
2002-07-16 18:09:00  0.023  0.073  0.000    NaN  0.014     5.8
```

Calculate a rounded time (the time I am converting to an int in nanoseconds, then rounding to the nearest 30*60 seconds). You may have to adjust if you want up or down (to the next 1/2 hour)

```
In [102]: new_index = pd.DatetimeIndex(int(1e9*30*60)*(np.round(df2.index.asi8/(1e9*30*60))).astype(np.int64)).values

In [104]: new_index
Out[104]: 
array(['2002-07-16T10:00:00.000000000-0400',
       '2002-07-16T12:00:00.000000000-0400',
       '2002-07-16T14:00:00.000000000-0400'], dtype='datetime64[ns]')
```

Copying just to avoid modifying the original frame. Set the new index

```
In [105]: df3 = df2.copy()

In [106]: df3.index = new_index
```

Subselect and join

```
In [107]: df1.loc[df3.index].join(df3)
Out[107]: 
                     Temp  SpCond   Sal  DO_pct  DO_mgl  Depth   pH  Turb   P04F   NH4F   N02F   N03F  NO23F  CHLA_N
2002-07-16 14:00:00  26.0   45.31  29.3    71.6     4.9   0.95  7.9    -5  0.053  0.073  0.005  0.021  0.026     8.6
2002-07-16 16:00:00  25.9   45.23  29.2    67.0     4.6   1.11  7.8    -6  0.029  0.069  0.002  0.016  0.018     9.6
2002-07-16 18:00:00  25.9   45.27  29.3    74.3     5.1   1.15  7.9    -6  0.023  0.073  0.000    NaN  0.014     5.8
```

Comment: see this for more info on rounding: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17781159/round-pandas-datetime-index