# Merging two pandas timeseries shifted by 1 second

Tags: python, merge, pandas, time-series, dataframe

I have two sets of time series like this.

One:

```
                         px
2014-03-17 07:55:00    527.890
2014-03-17 08:20:00    526.500
2014-03-17 08:25:00    526.535
2014-03-17 08:30:00    526.555
2014-03-17 08:35:00    526.770
2014-03-17 08:40:00    526.775
2014-03-17 08:45:00    526.885
2014-03-17 08:50:00    526.835
2014-03-17 08:55:00    527.190
```

The other:

```
                      ask   bid   mid
2014-03-17 13:25:01  9.30  9.10  9.200
2014-03-17 13:30:01  8.40  8.20  8.300
2014-03-17 13:35:01  7.70  7.55  7.625
2014-03-17 13:40:01  7.80  7.65  7.725
2014-03-17 13:45:01  7.80  7.70  7.750
2014-03-17 13:50:01  7.90  7.75  7.825
2014-03-17 13:55:01  8.25  8.05  8.150
2014-03-17 14:00:01  7.95  7.75  7.850
2014-03-17 14:05:01  8.15  8.00  8.075
2014-03-17 14:10:01  8.40  8.30  8.350
```

As you can see one of them is shifted by 1 second.
But I would like to treat them as same bucket. For instance, 2014-03-17 13:25:01 should be same as 2014-03-17 13:25:00. How can i achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind figured out one way to do it.

```
df['time'] = df.index - datetime.timedelta(seconds=1)
df.set_index(['time'], inplace=True)
```

And then I merge the two..

If there are better ways please do let me know.

Comment: Seems a reasonable way. You could also do: `df.index = df.index.values.astype('datetime64[m]')`.

Comment: you can also round the as well, see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17781159/round-pandas-datetime-index