# Matplotlib: plot number of observations per minute across all Mondays in a year

Tags: python, datetime, matplotlib

I have a pandas DataFrame where one of the columns is a bunch of dates (datetime type). I am trying to plot the number of observations per minute across all Mondays in a year against the minutes in the day.

For example, suppose I have two Mondays in my data and there are 3 observations at 09:01 on the first Monday and 4 observations at 09:01 on the second Monday. I would want to plot 7 (3+4) against 9*60+1=541 (That is, 09:01 is the 541st minute since the start of the day). Here is how I started:

```
def minutes_in_day(arg):
    #returns minute number in day  
    return arg.hour*60+arg.minute

def get_day(arg):
    return arg.isocalendar()[2]

# df is my pandas dataframe
df['day']=df['my_datetime_variable'].apply(get_day)
df['minute']=df['my_datetime_variable'].apply(minutes_in_day)
group=df.groupby(['day','minute'])
my_data=group['whatever_variable'].count()
```

my_data has two indices: a day index going from 1(Monday) to 7(Sunday) and a minute index going from potentially 0 to potentially 24*60-1=1439. How could I use matplotlib(pyplot) to plot the observation count against the minute index only when day index is 1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is more or less what you want:

```
#import modules
import random as randy 
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

#create sample dataset
idx=randy.sample(pd.date_range(start='1/1/2015',end='5/5/2015',freq='T'),2000)
idx.sort()
dfm=pd.DataFrame({'data':np.random.randint(0,2,len(idx))},index=idx)

#resample to fill in the gaps and groupby day of the week (0-6) and time
dfm=dfm.resample('T')
dfm=dfm.groupby([dfm.index.dayofweek,dfm.index.time]).count()

#Select monday (the '0th' day of the week) 
dfm=dfm.loc[0]

#plot
dfm.plot(title="Number of observations on Mondays",figsize=[12,5])
```

Gives

[image]

As you can read in the [pandas.DatetimeIndex docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DatetimeIndex.html), the `dayofweek`attribute returns the day of the week with Monday=0 - Sunday=6 and the `time` attribute   returns a `numpy` array of `datetime.time`.

Comment: Thanks, your answer is quite helpful. My problem is that I also have seconds in my datetime variables--that's why I originally used the `minutes_in_day` function. Do you have any idea of how to use the `index.time` to group by minute? Thanks

Comment: To avoid things like this it's always better to  give a reproducible example by e.g. making up some data as I did. To get what you want you can change the `groupby` to `dfm.groupby([dfm.index.dayofweek,dfm.index.hour,dfm.index.minute]).count()`. (Or if you want to round the `DatetimeIndex` from seconds to minutes you can use `pd.DatetimeIndex(((dfm.index.asi8/(1e9*60)).round()*1e9*60).astype(np.int64)).v‌​alues` as described [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17781159/round-pandas-datetime-index) .)